# Check that string_view won't outlive its string object

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `string_view` class which is intended to be a drop-in replacement for `std::string`:

```
struct string_view {
  /* implicit */ string_view(const std::string& s) : ptr_(s.c_str()), size_(s.size()) {}
  // other ctors...

  const char* ptr_;
  size_t size_;
};
```

However while it's OK to write

```
void f(string_view sv);
f(std::to_string(123));
```

The `string_view` cannot outlive temporary string object, it would lead to UB (use-after-free)

```
string_view g(string_view sv) { return sv; }
string_view sv = g(std::to_string(123));
sv[0];
```

Another case of UB:

```
string_view sv = std::to_string(123);
sv[0];
```

Is there a way to catch such errors at compile time? (Other than a Clang plugin).

Comment: Don't ever *store* a string view. That's not what it's for. Only use string views to *view* a string temporarily.

Comment: Rust has life time in its time. C++ doesn't. You have to use/write some static analyzer to catch some of these misuses for C++.

Comment: the main use of views is as argument for functions, instead of passing char[], you pass a view. don't use to something else.

Comment: @KerrekSB, that's wrong. Views are non-owning ranges. Like a pair of iterators. And it's OK to store and return iterators. And pairs of iterators. And views.

Comment: @Abyx: I didn't say you can't return a string view. You can. And you should. But nobody should *store* the result. "Should" as in "unless you know what you're doing", as always.

Answer (score 1):

Treat them like unmanaged non-owning pointers or references (without reference lifetime extension), because that is what they are.

Just like unmanaged pointers and references, the programmer is responsible for the lifetime management.

If you are willing to have immutable cow strings instead of `std::string`s as your baseline string you can write reference counting `string_view`s that ensure their source string outlives them (at run time).  With a bit of work, you could even add auto-fragmentation (when less than X% of the original source string remains "alive", start dismantling it).

(Cow = copy on write).

A basic immutable cow string uses a shared pointer to a const std string, and replicates most of the std strings read-only API.

To write to the cow string, you call `.extract()`, which returns a writable `std::string` (either a copy, or if the cow string is unique via move).

You write to that `std::string`, modifying it, then assign it back to the cow string.

Then augment the cow string with the view concept, where it can represent a subset of the buffer.  Next, add in systems to auto-fragment large buffers when only a small percent are being referenced (this part is tricky, especially doing it thread-safely and handling the case of a 1 meg string where there are a million cow strings all accessing the first 10 bytes).

This approach gives you "safe" strings and string views.

Comment: We are stuck with std::string aren't we?  I think making it mutable was, in retrospect, a mistake.